# Trouble getting all the user ids in a discord server using a Hikari bot

Tags: python, database, discord, bots

I am trying to code an exp leveling system in my discord bot and everything is done but one part i need to be able to get every single member of a guild when i join it but the problem is when i get the guild with `event.guild.get_members()` and try to iterate through it with `for member in members:` it tells me that it cant be iterated because its type snowflake which is the base class and i cant find any method any where to turn `event.guild.get_members()`  into member objects that i can get the userid from to put them in the database. If anyone has any methods to find all the user ids in the guild that would also work so if you have that i would count that as an answer.

Comment: I cant find any solutions so i have decided that instead of doing it when the bot join the guild i will check if the person is in the data base  when i try to give them exp if they are not in it then i will add them this is less efficient but not that less and if i find out how to do it my original way i will share it  here.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The snowflake is the id

Comment: really it is @Anu6is could you give me an example because i can do a loop on it do i need to run a function on it or acces a variable inside